# Why is the result of std::difftime inconsistent on Linux and Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I want to get the timing result in milliseconds, so I chose std::difftime because I think it is relatively simple, but after running on different platforms, I get different results. I checked cppreference and didn't see any related explanation.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int count = 10;
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i){
        auto st = std::clock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "sleep time is: " << std::difftime(std::clock(), st) << std::endl;
        //printf("time is: %.f\n", difftime(clock(), st));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*ubuntu*: Linux hgsrv 5.3.0-61-generic #55~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 16:40:20 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
*windows*: 20h2 19042.630
*g++ version*: g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
*vs version*: 2019 16.7.7

**result of linux:**

```
sleep time is: 89
sleep time is: 36
sleep time is: 29
sleep time is: 27
sleep time is: 27
sleep time is: 30
sleep time is: 29
sleep time is: 31
sleep time is: 28
sleep time is: 26
```

**result of Windows:**

```
sleep time is: 1004
sleep time is: 1011
sleep time is: 1014
sleep time is: 1001
sleep time is: 1009
sleep time is: 1011
sleep time is: 1011
sleep time is: 1006
sleep time is: 1003
sleep time is: 1010
```

Comment: Not too sure about the cause of the issue you refer to but `std::clock()` shouldn't be used at all as some of its implementations are very unreliable. Use `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock`.

Comment: `std::difftime` compares `time_t`s. `clock` doesn't return `time_t`s.

Comment: @user4581301 on windows, it looks like work fun

Comment: What are you expecting from `std::clock`? I need to know in order to understand what you are not understanding.

Comment: One thing to take into account is this bit from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock): *Returns the approximate processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related to the program's execution. To convert result value to seconds divide it by [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC).* You do not get wall clock time, nor do you necessarily get a recognizable or portable tick period.

Comment: As per [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/), `real_time` is approximate time `real_time' The time span after which the calling thread shall resume its execution.
Note that multi-threading management operations may cause certain delays beyond this.
duration is an object that represents a specific relative time.` Hence sleep time is an approximate sleep time

Comment: @user4581301  I just want to get a time measurement in milliseconds, it doesn't need to be too precise. I will try to divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC as you said, thanks for your guidance

Comment: @TruthSeeker   i know it's an approximate sleep time, I'm just wondering why the api of std has different results on different platforms

Comment: As mentioned by @user4581301, it's not the time difference in seconds. Along with that, [std::difftime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/difftime) expected input arguments are of type `std::time_t` not `std::clock`. refer the example for more clarity

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% convinced dividing the linux `clock` return value by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is going to work. What we see by the reported Linux numbers is around 30 tick per second.  The POSIX `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1000000. This doesn't jive.

Comment: here is the updated [code](http://cpp.sh/3c5cw). hope this solves your problem

Comment: Aha, finally, I gave up `difftime`, switching to a `std :: chrono :: system_clock`